# alert dialog from oncreate

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, splash-screen

I have an alert dialog started in onCreate that lets user to choose from two different activities to start from. I used the alert dialog box that has positive and negative values but unfortunately I get an error. Is it not possible to use this kind of alert dialogs to run two different activities? if yes how is it possible?
I get this kind of error:

```
[Android Application]   
[Android Application]   
[Android Application]   
[Android Application]   
[Android Application]   
[Android Application]   
[Android Application]   
[Android Application]   
    DalvikVM [localhost:8602]   
        Thread [<1> main] (Running) 
        Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
        Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
        Thread [<11> Thread-198] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))   
            <VM does not provide monitor information>   
            Handler.<init>(Handler$Callback, boolean) line: 200 
            Handler.<init>() line: 114  
            AlertDialog(Dialog).<init>(Context, int, boolean) line: 109 
            AlertDialog.<init>(Context, int, boolean) line: 114 
            AlertDialog$Builder.create() line: 931  
            MainActivity$splashscreen.run() line: 68    
[Android Application]
```

here is my code for the alert dialog box

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //ImageView image;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Removes title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    
        // Removes notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        splashscreen view = new splashscreen();
        view.start();

    }

    public class splashscreen extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(3*1000);
            }catch(Exception  e){
                Log.v("Exception", e.toString());
            }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                builder.setTitle("Choose your activity to start");

                builder.setMessage("Pick desired activity");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Office",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OfficeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(home);
                        finish();
                        //dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("School", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SchoolActivity.class);
                        startActivity(home);
                        finish();
                        //dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertdialog=builder.create();
                alertdialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible. Trust me. The only thing you should avoid is touching ui elements in a different thread from the ui thread

Comment: `i get this kind of error` ... and what's the **real** error?

Comment: im been looking for it for hours i dont know what im doing wrong here..still looking for answers

Comment: on which line it is giving you error?

Comment: @blackbelt what do you mean by avoid touching UI elements in a different thread?

Comment: AlertDialog is an UI Widgets, and it should be managed by the UI Thread.

Comment: line 68 is 'AlertDialog alertdialog=builder.create();' according to debug this is where i get error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the solution for your problem,try this...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose your activity to start");
            builder.setMessage("Pick desired activity");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Office",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OfficeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("School", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SchoolActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertdialog=builder.create();
            alertdialog.show();
        }
    }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: its working nicely sir but what im trying to achieve here is after splash alert dialog will pop allowing user to choose which activity to start..any idea on it

Comment: @Hak Hak did you tried this code??? It shows a popup dialog after the splash... If you want any further details,explain a little more about your problem..

Comment: but what i want to happened is when the splash is over then the dialog will show any ideas on this matter?

Comment: @Hak Hak When i tested my code i got perfect output, did you changed anything in my code?? Create new projct and paste my code there, If it does not work, let me know..

Comment: no i didnt are you running it on device because im running it on emulator maybe that is why it has delay..i mean if i select any button the is a bit of delay before the selected activity is shown.but the code is really perfect

Comment: Some explanation about the code could be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

To display your **AlertDialog** run your code in the **UI Thread**

Try this..

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // Your code to run in GUI thread here
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont understand your answer please explain more where should i put it what should i put in here?